# Missing icons in budspencer theme on fish shell

Tags: fish, budspencer, oh-my-fish

I'm trying to install the budspencer theme for the fish shell. I install the theme using Oh-My-Fish with command

```
omf install budspencer
```

And although I installed the powerline fonts from https://github.com/powerline/fonts using the provided script (`./install.sh`), I'm still seeing missing icons from the prompt.

[image]

Any idea what I need to do fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I needed to set the font in iTerm 2 manually. This fixed it

[image]